# How to change the button in the first row of a HTML table using DOM ? (Adding and removing rows by DOM)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here in the below fiddle, i am trying to add and remove table rows using DOM. As per the script the last field of every row will have a delete button. But i want the delete button in the first field to be the add button which is outside the table.

Only the button in the first row should be add row button. rest of the row should have delete button as it is. How can i do this ?

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7AeDQ/33/

### Javascript

```
function deleteRow(row)
{
    var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
}


function insRow()
{
    console.log( 'hi');
    var x=document.getElementById('POITable');
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var len = x.rows.length;
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp1.id += len;
    inp1.value = '';
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.id += len;
    inp2.value = '';
    x.appendChild( new_row );
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="POItablediv">
            <input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="Add More POIs" onclick="insRow()"/>
    <table id="POITable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>POI</td>
            <td>Latitude</td>
            <td>Longitude</td>
            <td>Delete?</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox"/></td>
            <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" readonly=true/></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create new rows by cloning an existing row (and existing button). If you want the behaviour of the button in the first row to be different from other rows, you need to override that changed behaviour in your insRow function (as you do for input ids currently).

Try changing your code to:

HTML:

```
...
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox"/></td>
    <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" readonly=true/></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Add More POIs" onclick="insRow()"/></td>
</tr>
...
```

JS:

```
function deleteRow(evt) {
    var i = evt.target.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
}


function insRow() {
    var x = document.getElementById('POITable');
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var len = x.rows.length;

    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp1.id += len;
    inp1.value = '';

    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.id += len;
    inp2.value = '';

    var button = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    button.value = "Delete row";
    button.onclick = function(it) {deleteRow(it)};

    x.appendChild( new_row );    
}
```

Comment: wow thanks...it worked..:) here is your change in fiddle..hopefully it could help someone else looking for the same issue..thanks again..http://jsfiddle.net/7AeDQ/61/

Answer (score 1):

I can guess your table will be generated dynamically, that is why you having the issue.

A jQuery solution, as you have tagged it:

```
$(function(){
    $("#POITable tr").eq(1).find('td:last').html('<input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="Add More POIs" onclick="insRow()"/>');
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7AeDQ/59/

Also your delete button will appear multiple times so don't use a fixed `id` for it as you used:

```
<input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/>
```

Rather use a `class` or use incremental id like  `id="delPOIbutton-1"`, `id="delPOIbutton-2"`

Comment: I want to the add button instead of the delete button in the same position. because when the user can simply delete the first row, it the dom will not generate any more rows.

Comment: Here in the above fiddle, you replaced add button with the delete button in all rows, but i want that to happen ONLY in the first row and rest of the rows i want the delete button. Hope u understood me..

Comment: I have not replaced in all rows, to make sure check this http://jsfiddle.net/7AeDQ/62/

Comment: after two three rows again the add button is coming instead of delete button in the above fiddle..! please check socha23's answer in fiddle. it works

Comment: It's impossible, check this with so many rows http://jsfiddle.net/7AeDQ/63/ . Anyway glad to know its working :)